# How to prevent !! via ktlint?

Tags: kotlin, ktlint

I have enabled ktlint im my Android Studio project and its running fine.

Since there are standard Kotlin rules enabled, I would like to extend its standard rule set in order to prevent `!!`? I do not want to have any `!!` occurences in my repository.

How can I configure the standard rule set so it revents `!!` in code?